# Change the value of a dropdown if it is equal to something

Tags: javascript

Sorry if this question has already been asked and answered, but I couldn't find anything specifically for my needs. I have a form that has placeholders and javascript to make sure the form isn't submitted with the placeholders still there. There is a dropdown box that has the value of 'Best time to call'. What I want to do is if this value is passed as the default, I want it to change to something like "n/a" or a blank value. I have achieved this with the comments box using the following javascript, but it doesn't seem to work the same for the dropdown:

```
var comments=document.getElementById('comments').value;
    if (comments=="Comments")
      {
      document.getElementById('comments').value="";
      }
```

This isn't a required field so I can't have an alert come up, so I just need to value to be changed if submitted as 'Best time to call'. Hope I have explained everything correctly

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't you select have value ids?

```
<select id="hours">
  <option value="default">Best Time To Call</option>
  <option value="six" >6</option>
  <option value="seven">7</option>
</select>
```

If so you can use this:

```
var e = document.getElementById("hours");
var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
if(value == "default")
  e.value ="six";
```

**UPDATE: I have changed the behaviour to set it to first option after default**.

Comment: My select has value id's. They're aren't numeric values though. Do I get around this with if(e.selectedIndex == "value here")?
Also, how would I then change the value?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [HTML5 Placeholder](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder) text;

```
<textarea id="comments" placeholder="Comments" />
```

This way you don't need to put validation in place to workaround your custom placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

For dropdown you need to loop thru all the "option"s, find the one that has that value (Comments in your case) and add attribute to that "option" - selected.

Instead if you are using jQuery, using jQuery("#comments").val("") will work.